# Desconsiderar palavras no input

Tags: javascript, jquery, formulário, input, text

Gostaria de saber como anular/desconsiderar certas alavras colocadas pelos usuarios no input.

Eu tenho um input onde o pessoa deveria me enviar a URL de um site, no caso deveiram enviar a url como site.com/imagem pois eu tenho um script que pega o resto da informação.

Mas acontece que as pessoas colocam no input coisas como site.com/image1.jpg, site.com/image2.jpg site.com/image3.jpg e assim da erro.

Minha dúvida é como eu faço para ANULAR CERTAS PALAVRAS NO INPUT como: imagem1.jpg, imagem2.jpg. Assim a pesoa pode enviar o link errado mas o script iria desconsiderar essas serie de palavras erradas.
Ou o escript poderia fazer um replace e subistituir certas palavras por um espaço em branco (tmb resolveria)

Eu tentei este script : http://jsfiddle.net/6hxspv14/2/
Mas na pratica ele não funciona quando clico no botão submit
desculpe a dificuldade de me expressar estou inciando na programação .

meu código input:

```
<form action="thumbs.php" method="post">
URL da thumb: <input type="text" class="restrict"  name="url"><br>
<input  type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Mas esse script não tem submit...

Comment: Sim, eu digo que testei este script no meu código original mas não funcionou

Comment: você quer anular certas palavras ou um padrão de palavras ?

Comment: Na verdade é um padrão.

1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jjgp ... até o 30.jpg

porque os usuarios estao inserindo site/img/1.jpg

então o resultado é site/img/1.jpg.1.jpg pois eu já peguei essa parametro no php. por isso preciso anular estes no input

Comment: Podes colocar o código do seu input ? Em sua pergunta tem um link [editar] edite e coloque o código relevante, na barra de controle tem as {chaves}, selecione todo seu código e clique nas chaves...

Comment: <form action="thumbs.php" method="post">
URL da thumb: <input type="text" class="restrict"  name="url"><br>
<input  type="submit">
</form>

Comment: Podes colocar em sua pergunta através da edição ?

Comment: pronto, coloquei ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A forma que me veio a mente é utilizando `ER(expressão regular)` e o método `replace()`.

```html
<form action="" method="post">
URL da thumb: <input type="text" class="restrict"  name="url" value=""/><br/>
<input  type="submit" onclick="replaceURL()" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
<script>
function replaceURL()
{ var inputURL = document.getElementsByClassName("restrict")[0].value;//captura o valor do input
 var replaceurl = inputURL.replace(/\.[\d]{1,2}\.jpg/, " ");//substitui o valor capturado pela "ER" por " "
 /* "ER" explicação
  * "\." encontra o "." literalmente uma vez que ele é um operador é necessária a "\" para escapar e torná-lo literal
  * "[\d]{1,2}" encontra o número em uma ou duas ocorrências dentro da lista [\d] que por sua vez é uma abreviação para os dígitos[0-9]
  * "\.jpg" encontra a extensão(repara na "\" novamente para escapar o ponto)
  *  */
 var inputFianl = document.getElementsByClassName("restrict")[0].value = replaceurl;//atribui o resultado da substituição ao valor do input
 alert("O valor atual do input é : "+inputFianl);//alerta o resultado final, só para você ver pois após o submit a pagina é recarregada pois o action=""
}  
</script>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo, funcionou certinho. Eu pensei que teria que usar Jquery mas sua solução foi extremamente eficaz. Ajudou muito!!

Comment: Considere validar uma das repostas clicando no incon verde abaixo das setas de avaliação.. Boa Sorte...